# How to obtain the inputs to Quicksort

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I read that the input to the quicksort algorithm usually is the array (A) that needs to be sorted, the greatest value in the array (hi), and the lowest value in the array (lo).

I'm a bit confused about how you would even know the values of hi and lo. Typically, when given an unsorted array, I was under the impression that you have no prior knowledge about the values in the array.

Comment: Go back and look at what hi and lo are. They have to do with the indexes, not the values. There are various examples you can find that show the recursive execution with the inputs to each call. An example like that would help you comprehend what those indexes are

Answer (score 1):

Even if you needed to find min and max values for quicksort, you can just scan the input for those values. Quicksort is  `O(n*log (n))`. Min and max just `O(n)`. There is no harm in determining min and max.